# Set Focus on first focusable control inside containers(Ex : tableLayoutPanel,FlowlayoutPanel,GroupBox...)

Tags: c#, winforms

I have scenario where , I would like to focus on first control inside the container.

1. Panel inside panel also exist
2. First control of the panel inside panel may or may not focusable
3. First panel may or may not have the control, In this case it should point to next focusable item.

For this i wrote piece of code:

```
Control FirstFocusableControl;

static public Control FocusFirstControl(Control ctrl)
{
    FirstFocusableControl = null;
    GetFirstControl(ctrl);
    return FirstFocusableControl;
}

//Get first control from Containers control
static public void GetFirstControl(Control ctrl)
{
    foreach (Control ctrlItem in ctrl.Controls)
    {
        //if (ctrlItem is Panel || ctrlItem is GroupBox)
        if(ctrlItem.HasChildren )
        {
             GetFirstControl(ctrlItem);
        }
        //if control is not a containers,Tababble,enabled,visible to user and control length  is more than zero size 
        else if (ctrlItem is Control && ctrlItem.TabStop && ctrlItem.Enabled && ctrlItem.Visible && ctrlItem.Size.Width > 0)
        {
            FirstFocusableControl = ctrlItem;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

but few scenarios such as 
TableLayout panel containing the panel , intern if it contain one more panel means
Form -> TableLayoutPanel-> Panel ->Panel -> Control is failing.

I tried all the way to debug the code. 
but always I am getting focus on next control
ie. Form -> TextBox.
Please let me know the way to achieve this issue..

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.getnextcontrol(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should return after GetFirstControl(ctrlItem);
Please try the following code.

```
public bool GetFirstControl(Control ctrl)
    {
        foreach (Control ctrlItem in ctrl.Controls)
        {
            if (ctrlItem.HasChildren)
            {
                if(GetFirstControl(ctrlItem))
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            else if (ctrlItem is Control && ctrlItem.CanFocus && ctrlItem.TabStop && ctrlItem.Enabled && ctrlItem.Visible && ctrlItem.Size.Width > 0)
            {
                ctrlItem.Focus();
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```